# phpunit in phpstorm issue - Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to get phpunit to work inside phpstorm and I'm getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found
```

I'm using version 7.1.12 of php and phpunit version 7.1.5.

I've searched for solutions to this but can't find anything that's been able to help me.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: The Test Configuration]

The Test Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` class in PHPUnit 6. Since version 6 PHPUnit uses namespaces, so you should use `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` instead. If you cant do this, you should downgrade to PHPUnit 5 or create aliases for missing classes:

```
if (!class_exists('PHPUnit_Framework_Assert')) {
    class_alias('PHPUnit\Framework\Assert', 'PHPUnit_Framework_Assert');
}

if (!class_exists('PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase')) {
    class_alias('PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase', 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm needs to be able to locate and run PHPUnit. If your project uses `composer` you can configure it to load it from there. If not, PHPStorm can download it for you. [image: Setting up PHPUnit in PHP Storm]

Comment: Thanks of the reply. I tried that and got the same error. The version of PHPUnit I have is 6.2.4. Should I downgrade to 5.7.27 and try that?

Comment: What PHP Storm are you running?

Comment: I'm using version 2018.1.2

Comment: You could downgrade to PHP Unit 5.x and it will probably work. I find strange that PHP Storm did not detect the correct version to use. Maybe you are not using composer to get PhpUnit as I've shown in the posted image.

Comment: I downgraded to 5.7.27 - I'm now getting this error:


/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.12/bin/php /private/var/folders/gp/v8rj_29j1p9bsbh_x790dq440000gp/T/ide-phpunit.php --configuration /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag221/dev/tests/unit/framework/autoload.php Magento\Framework\Api\Test\Unit\DemoTest /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag221/dev/tests/static/DemoTest.php
Could not load "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag221/dev/tests/unit/framework/autoload.php".

ParsePI: PI php never end ...

Start tag expected, '<' not found

Comment: Can you get phpunit to run from the command line first? That may be a better idea!

Comment: I ended up doing that, from tests folder this worked

../../vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap ../../vendor/autoload.php static/DemoTest.php

Comment: So, then, if you configure PhpStorm as it is the picture I've posted in my answer it should run the same command - meaning it should use the phpunit form your vendor folder. It should also detect the version you expect to see.